# I am working on airline management system. Here User enters the selected destination from shown destinations,so it's showing INVALID DESTINATION

Tags: c++

```
string dest;
string local_des[4]={"HYDERABAD","KOLKATA","GWALIOR","DELHI"};
string inter_des[5]={"USA","PARIS","DUBAI","LAS VEGAS","LONDON"};
char option;
cout<<"\nPlease select your destination type:\n";
cout<<"1.Local Destinations\n";
cout<<"2.International Destinations\n";
cout<<"\nENTER YOUR CHOICE(1 or 2)\n";
cin>>option;
stat=0;
switch(option){
    case '1':
    for(a=0;a<4;a++){
        cout<<"\n"<<local_des[a];
    }
    cout<<"Now Enter Your Destination(IN BLOCK LETTERS):";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,dest);
     
     
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(dest==local_des[i]){
            stat=1;
        }
        else{
            stat=0;
        }
    
    }
    if(stat==1){
        cout<<"DESTINATION CONFIRMED!\n";
    }   
    else{
       cout<<"INVALID DESTINATION\n";
    }
     
    break;


    case '2':
    for(b=0;b<5;b++){
        cout<<inter_des[b];
    }
    cout<<"Now Enter Your Destination(IN BLOCK LETTERS):";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,dest); 
     
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){

        if(dest==inter_des[j]){
            stat=1;
        }
        else{
            stat=0;
        }
    
    }
    if(stat==1){
        cout<<"DESTINATION CONFIRMED!\n";
    }   
    else{
       cout<<"INVALID DESTINATION\n";
    }
    break;

    default:
    cout<<"INVALID OPTION";
}
```

I am working on airline management system where i need to show destinations for users. In above code, You can see switch statements,so whatever user inputs as destination ,it's throwing INVALID DESTINATION  as output.It will be very helpfull if anyone can help with this bug.Thanks in advance:)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could use a debugger on your code to show us which invalid destination is being printed.

Comment: Put a `break;` after `stat=1;`

Comment: Could you please try to formulate the question in the title in a general way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to fix this loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

    if (dest == inter_des[j]) {
        stat = 1;
    }
    else {
        stat = 0; // Resets stat to 0
    }
}
```

Currently stat will be 0 unless the last item in the inter_des was the same as dest. That is because every time that dest is not matched to the current item it sets stat to 0 even if it had already found a match earlier in the loop.

Instead you want this which will set stat to 1 if dest is found in any position and end the loop when it is found:

```
stat=0; 
for (int j = 0; j < 5 && stat == 0; j++) {
    if (dest == inter_des[j]) {
        stat = 1;
        // The loop will end on the next iteration because stat is no longer 0
    }
}
```

You have the same bug in the loop for local_des[].

Comment: Thankyou so much for your valuable responses. I understood my mistake and code is working perfectly now!